# Strong tags new line

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have problem with my strong tag. I'm using bootstrap to hide and view word based on responsive css but i have style issue wher strong tag will start new line on browser

```
<strong class="visible-desktop hidden-tablet hidden-phone"> Software/</strong> <strong class="hidden-desktop visible-tablet visible-phone">Web/</strong><strong class="hidden-desktop hidden-tablet visible-phone">Mobile</strong> Developer
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Bootstrap 2.3.2 `.visible-desktop` has this rule `display: inherit !important;`
So if your strong tag is inside a div (or any other block type element) then it will inherit the block type behavior.
Either set `display: inline !important;` or maybe place it in a span to fix this.

Comment: I'd argue that using !important is usually bad practice, but given that bootstrap is already using it, there's not much else to do :/

Comment: I personally try to avoid css frameworks like bootstrap as much as possible. i find it so much easier to build custom breakpoints as i have more direct control

Comment: Using Bootstrap 4 and just googled this issue. For me ``display: inline !important`` doesn't work... :(

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css.

```
strong {
    display:inline !important;
}
```