# thymeleaf utext / th:utext is inserting a newline on its own, why?

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf, newline

The use of simple html tags in a `th:utext` appears to be causing an errant newline to be rendered.  Why is that, and/or how do I prevent it?

My markup looks like this:

```
<div class="row mb-1" th:utext="${item.snippet}"></div>
```

My Java looks like this:

```
snippet = StringUtils.replaceIgnoreCase(snippet, 
searchText.trim(), 
"<strong>"+searchText.trim().toUpperCase()+"</strong>");
```

When `snippet` is "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs"; `searchText` is "jumped"; and the `strong` tags are present; the html is rendered like this:

```
The quick brown fox
<strong>JUMPED</strong>
over the lazy dogs
```

When I remove the `strong` tags, the html is rendered like this:

```
The quick brown fox JUMPED over the lazy dogs
```

Of note, I'm not talking JUST about how it appears in the browser; the source actually shows a newline after the `</strong>`; and no newline when the `</strong>` isn't present.  I have confirmed it's not being added in the Java layer, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an "inline expression:"

```xml
<div class="row mb-1">[(${item.snippet})]</div>
```

documented [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#expression-inlining).

As for *why*, I had a similar template and noticed the behavior change upon the release of Thymeleaf 3.0.  When describing inline expressions, the [issue](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/394) describes the equivalent as:

```xml
<div class="row mb-1"><th:block th:utext="${item.snippet}"/></div>
```

The behavior suggests there is additional text processing for some or all tags and `<th:block th:utext"..."/>` must insulate the target text.

Comment: I tried both of these examples and the same errant newline is rendered.  Very odd.

Comment: I agree.  BTW, you call `.toUpperCase()` in your Java code but your HTML snippets don't show upper case -- Do you know what is going on there?

Comment: There seems to be some relevant context missing. Is "item" just a POJO?

Comment: It is rendered in upper case; I missed that when sanitizing the snippet for upload.  item is a single pojo from a list, with a th:each used to iterate over it.

Comment: Turns out?  This is not a thymeleaf issue at all; it's a dupe of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419254/strong-tags-new-line